# Provide same event handler to multiple instances

Tags: c++, algorithm, events, poco

I have a `Shape` class in my program that has some hit testing logic to figure out if the user clicked inside the shape or not.

**Shape.h**

```
class Shape
{
    Event<ShapeArgs> balloonBurst;
    virtual void onMousePress(); //called when hit test is true on user's click
    private:
    bool hitTest(int x, int y);
};
```

**Shape.cpp**

```
virtual void onMousePress()
{
    cout<<"Clicked inside the shape";
    ShapeArgs arg;
    arg.name = "XYZ";
    NotifyEvent(balloonBurst, arg);
}
```

The main class has multiple instances of the above shape class
**Main program: (Main.h)**

```
vector<Shape*> shapes;
void handleShape(ShapeArgs &e);
```

.cpp

```
main()
{
    for(int i=0;i<10;++i){
        Shape *shape = new Shape(Color Color, string URL);
        shapes.push_back(shape);
    }
}
```

Now, I have to listen to the `balloonBurst` event of the `Shape` instances above. If I would have a single instance, I would have done something like the following:

```
AddListener(shape->balloonBurst, this, &MainProgram::handleBalloonBurst); //where shape is a single instance`
```

However, I have multiple  instances here and I am not sure how I should subscribe to them and provide the same handler method to the balloon (To be noted: Balloonburst event is not doing something that is not specific to that balloon, so unlike `C#` `sender` is not important to me in this event). `handleballoonBurst(ShapeArgs &e)` will be doing a separate thing (not specific to the balloon from where the event came)

How do I listen to the events of all the balloon shape instances here and provide a single handler method?

Comment: Why `C#` tag? the question has nothing to do with `C#`.

Comment: @Nawaz : The `Poco event framework` that I am using here in my project is very similar to C#. So, I thought those folks might alos be able to help.

Comment: "Not doing something that is not specific"? Is that correct?